# how to create a trigger in concatenating a auto_increment value column and a column that has a default value

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `grade_one_BINS`
 BEFORE INSERT ON `grade_one` FOR EACH ROW
set new.student_no = concat(new.letter, ' - ',new.num)
```

there is a problem in concatenating the num column that has auto increment value since the trigger is for before insert cause it will show a 0 value since the auto increment is still 0 until you insert some values...can you help me???

Comment: Make it an after insert trigger?

Comment: @N.B.: You can't change the `student_no` in an after trigger

Comment: @juergend - correct, my mistake for "speaking" before checking whether it'd work :)

Comment: @N.B. what do you suggest???thank you

Comment: @juergend what do you suggest???

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't store data again in another column that you already have in the `num` and `letter` columns.

You can generate the `student_no` column on-the-fly in your selects like this

```
select *,
       concat(letter, ' - ', num) as student_no
from your_table
```

Comment: is that code will automatically concatenate column num and letter when i input new values???

Comment: Yes, every time you run this select then the current values from the DB will be used.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What is not working? What do you expect and what do you get?